# Division in Summations

Tags: calculus, summation

Suppose $a_n=\dfrac{2^n}{n(n+2)}$ and $b_n=\dfrac{3^n}{5n+18}$.

I need to find the value of:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$$

I think this problem is meant for me to compute each sum differently and then divide. Is this some property of summations that we need to utilize here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split} 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n} 
& 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n(5n+18)}{3^nn(n+2)} \\ 
& 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \left(\frac{5}{n+2} + 9\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2} \right) \right) \right] \\ 
& 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \left(\frac{9}{n} - \frac{4}{n+2}\right) \right] \\ 
&
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{3^{n-2}n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n+2}}{3^n(n+2)} \\ 
&
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{3^{n-2}n} - \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{2^{n}}{3^{n-2}n} \\ 
&
 = \sum_{n=1}^2 \frac{2^n}{3^{n-2}n} = \frac{2}{3^{-1}} + \frac{2^2}{3^{0}2} \\
& 
 = 6 + 2 \\
&
 = 8 \end{split} \end{equation} $$

Comment: Ah,  the magic cancellation of homework problems!